# How to extract all elements from a data frame that are equal to any elements of a vector?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, extract

For example I have a data frame with 2 variables, ID and X, with values in X that can be repeated and I need to extract the ID from the all elements that their values in X be 3 or 4.

```
ID<-1:100
X<-round(runif(100,1,10))
data<-data.frame(ID,X)
```

If I trying extract them so

```
data$ID[data$X==c(3,4)]
```

I just extract some ID that are equal to 3 and some ID that are equal to 4. How could it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `%in%` instead of `==`.  Using `==` will only match the first element of `c(3,4)`

```
with(data, ID[X %in% c(3, 4)])
```

You could also write your sentence *"...I need to extract the ID from the all elements that their values in X be 3 or 4."* into a logical statement

```
with(data, ID[X == 3 | X == 4])
```

Comment: Thanks you so much It has helped me

Answer (score 1):

You can try `data.table`s binary search

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data), X)[J(c(3, 4))]$ID
```

Or `%between%`

```
setDT(data)[X %between% c(3, 4)]$ID
```

Why? Because of efficiency, for example:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e7
ID <- seq_len(n)
X <- round(runif(n, 1, 10))
data <- data.frame(ID, X)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

all.equal(setkey(setDT(data), X)[J(c(3,4))]$ID, with(data, ID[X %in% c(3, 4)]))
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(with(data, ID[X %in% c(3, 4)]), setDT(data)[X %between% c(3, 4)]$ID)
## [1] TRUE

data2 <- copy(data)


microbenchmark(DTbinsearch = setkey(setDT(data2), X)[J(c(3, 4))]$ID,
               DTbetween = setDT(data2)[X %between% c(3, 4)]$ID,
               Richard1 = with(data, ID[X %in% c(3, 4)]),
               Richard2 = with(data, ID[X == 3 | X == 4]))

# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# DTbinsearch 101.8367 103.9708 119.3839 107.0190 120.0599 266.7725   100
#   DTbetween 322.0519 331.0178 352.8798 344.8267 373.1562 433.3817   100
#    Richard1 465.2885 476.6722 505.3128 492.8427 525.6999 657.7406   100
#    Richard2 521.2169 532.5552 554.0807 542.3962 573.8510 671.9143   100
```